# PyQt5 concurrent mainLoop

Tags: python, pyqt5

Attempt at running pyqt5 in a thread (going to be running multiples so needs thread so as to be non-blocking). This example should launch a 25x25 headless window at 50,50, and change background if on left or right side of screen. Can get it working without threading, but I need the threading functionality

Edit:

```
import sys
import threading
import pynput
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget


class Overlay(threading.Thread):
    mouse = pynput.mouse.Controller
    tr, tg, tb = None, None, None
    fr, fg, fb = None, None, None
    xloc, yloc, width, height = None, None, None, None

    def __init__(self, x, y, w=25, h=25, r=255, g=255, b=255, rr=0, gg=0, bb=0):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.App = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.mainloop = QTimer(self.window)
        self.tr, self.tg, self.tb = r, g, b
        self.fr, self.fg, self.fb = rr, gg, bb
        self.xloc, self.yloc, self.width, self.height = x, y, w, h
        self.window.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.window.setGeometry(self.xloc, self.yloc, self.width, self.height)
        self.mainloop.timeout.connect(self.mainLoop)
        self.mainloop.start()
        self.window.show()

    def run(self):
        self.App.exec()

    def mainLoop(self):
        if self.mouse.position[0] > 960:
            self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: red;")
        else:
            self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: blue;")


thread = Overlay(50, 50)
thread.start()
print("Non blocking")
while True:
    print("running")
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: First of all, GUI elements should always be created and accessed from the main Qt thread, no from another one. Besides that, you are already using a QTimer, using another loop is completely unnecessary, at least for the given example.

Comment: The only element I'll be changing is the background-color. It only changes it own background, wouldn't access another thread to do this. I just need to make it threadable so that I can run multiples along side each other. The eventual 'goal' is to make a dock of windows whose backgrounds change independent of each other. The condition checking will be intensive, so I don't want to lag-out the others

Comment: @joeyleavell Seems like an XY problem to me, just run heavy tasks on another thread, and painting is not a heavy task.You want Qt to adapt to its design but unfortunately it is such a complex SW that establishes basic rules as already pointed out in the previous comments and that cannot be changed.